# Count the occurrences of 3 gram terms within multiple files

Tags: python

I have a list of 3-gram terms of around 10000 in a .txt file. I want to match these terms within multiple .GHC files under a directory and count the occurrences of each of the terms.

One of these files looks like this:

> ntdll.dll+0x1e8bd ntdll.dll+0x11a7 ntdll.dll+0x1e6f4 kernel32.dll+0xaa7f kernel32.dll+0xb50b ntdll.dll+0x1e8bd ntdll.dll+0x11a7 ntdll.dll+0x1e6f4 kernel32.dll+0xaa7f kernel32.dll+0xb50b ntdll.dll+0x1e8bd ntdll.dll+0x11a7 ntdll.dll+0x1e6f4 kernel32.dll+0xaa7f kernel32.dll+0xb50b ntdll.dll+0x1e8bd ntdll.dll+0x11a7 ntdll.dll+0x1e6f4 kernel32.dll+0xaa7f kernel32.dll+0xb50b kernel32.dll+0xb511 kernel32.dll+0x16d4f

I want the resulting output to be like this in a dataframe:

```
N_gram_term_1 N_gram_term_2 ............ N_gram_term_n
2             1                          0
3             2                          4
3             0                          3
```

the 2nd line here indicates that N_gram_term_1 has appeared 2 times in one file and N_gram_term_2 1 time and so on.

the 3rd line indicates that N_gram_term_1 has appeared 3 times in second file and N_gram_term_2 2 times and so on.

If I need to be more clear about something, please let me know.

Comment: Is this "ntdll.dll+0x1e8bd ntdll.dll+0x11a7 ntdll.dll+0x1e6f4 kernel32.dll+0xaa7f kernel32.dll+0xb50b" equal to N_gram_term_1 ?

Comment: Here N_gram_term_1 is itself a 3 string term that's why it is called 3 gram. I have to match this 3-gram term and count the occurrences of this term in each file in the directory. for example, my 3-gram term is {ntdll.dll+0x1e8bd ntdll.dll+0x11a7 ntdll.dll+0x1e6f4} so for the given sample of file it will be 4.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have implementations for this purpoes, perhaps in sklearn. A simple implementation from scratch, though would be:

```
import sys                                                                      
                                                                                
d = {}  # dictionary that will have 1st key = file and 2 key = 3gram                                                                        
for file in sys.argv[1:]:  # These are all files to be analyzed                                                  
    d[file] = {}  # The value here is a nested dictionary                                                              
    with open(file) as f:  # Opening each file at a time                   
        for line in f:     # going through every row of the file                                                     
            g = line.strip()                                                    
                                                                                
            if g in d[file]:                                                    
                d[file][g] +=1                                                  
            else:                                                               
                d[file][g] = 1                                                  
                                                                                
import pandas                                                                   
print(pandas.DataFrame(d).T)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Here N_gram_term_1 is itself a 3 string term that's why it is called 3 gram. I have to match this 3-gram term and count the occurrences of this term in each file in the directory. for example, my 3-gram term is {ntdll.dll+0x1e8bd ntdll.dll+0x11a7 ntdll.dll+0x1e6f4} so for the given sample of file it will be 4. @aerijman

Comment: A single 3-gram per row?

Comment: each 3-gram term will be the column and the rows would be the number of times these terms occur in the files in the directory.

Comment: first row for first file, second row for second file and so on.

Comment: @mathque33 I transpose the dataframe for you.

Comment: @mathque33 Did you tried the new answer with DataFrame(d).T -> for Transposed ?

Comment: is a dictionary. I first make a dictionary and then shape it into a dataframe

Comment: what is d[file]?

Comment: I updated the answer with comments. I recommend you to look into python dictionoaries or hashes if you come from other languages and everything will make more sense to you.

Comment: and where is the file with 3-gram terms that we have to match?

Comment: @mathque33 I updated the question with comments. Try to play with the script to understand each of the things and let me know if the answer fit your expected output. Thank you

Comment: the comments show the files to be analyzed but I can't understand where is the file in which 3-gram terms are there that we have to match

Comment: You should run the scripit as `python <name-you-give-to-this-script>.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt... fileN.txt`